# Filters on mobile require reading illegible text in cookie consent to disable them

Tags: bug, status-completed, privacy, accessibility, april-fools

When opening a Stack Overflow page for the first time on mobile, the controls to disable or change the filters are entirely covered by the cookie consent dialog, which is ...quite difficult to read with certain filters enabled.

Probably the filters should not affect the cookie consent screen, or at least appear over top of it.

[image: Blurry cookie consent dialog]
[image: Blurry cookie consent details]

Comment: The “Facebook”-like filter was the one presented to me first and I assumed that’s what everyone gets to see first. _That_ would be fine. Or “Frisa Lank” or even “Windows 3.1”.

Comment: Wow, I thought they were hacked…

Comment: @Sebastian True, there've been a bunch of complaints about the 3D filter. I can also imagine people having trouble with the Terminal filter since some of the text is so small.